# What's the benefits to implement swift instance methods as currying functions?

Tags: swift, swift2

I read that swift instance methods are implemented as currying function?
(see http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/)

```
class BankAccount {
    var balance: Double = 0.0

    func deposit(amount: Double) {
       balance += amount
   }   
}

BankAccount.deposit(account)(100)
```

There are twice function call. It's not efficient. The swift compiler can optimize this simple case. But for complex inheritance, the two function call is necessary, especially for code:

```
let depositor = self.dynamicType.deposit
depositor(account)(100).
```

This is less efficient that the C++ virtual function call. In C++, there is only one function call.

The type of desposit is: `BankAccount -> (Double) -> ()`. I expect it as `(BankAccount, Double) -> ()` like in C++

Does anybody know what's the benefit to implement instance method as currying methods? Why swift does not just implement instance method just like C++?

Comment: Unless you want a purely academic explanation, you might want to move on as currying has been removed in Swift 3.  Writing any code that relies on it will be obsolete soon.

Comment: @par Currying has not been removed from Swift 3, [only the special currying syntax](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0002-remove-currying.md) (which isn't relevant to OP's example in any case).

Comment: Thanks par for your reply. I see the document. https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0002-remove-currying.md.
But the internal instance method implementation will not changed per this documents.

Comment: @Hamish Thank you for the clarification, I misunderstood the proposal.